# How to make a time restricted web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am developing an online ordering system (in C# ASP.NET) for a certain company. Their main requirement is to only allow their dealers to order during a specified time window (8 a.m. to 12 p.m.).

As for the security, I get the current time from the server side with a `select getdate()` SQL command in the code behind file of my web page.

I am getting that time in `DATETIME` format. I only want to get the time, so I call `DateTime.toShortTimeString()`, but this gives me a string on which I cannot apply any time calculations. Please note that I cannot use `System.DateTime.Now` because it will give me the client-side date. If a client changes their PC date, my web page may become available outside the specified time window.

How can I compare the time values? Should I use `TimeSpan` and, if so, how?

Comment: Also note that, i dont want to show this page unless the current time is between 8am to 12pm

Comment: Are you taking timezones into effect or is this only within one timezone?

Comment: hello all, i am sorry that i forgot to mention that i am not taking time zones in effect

Comment: Instead of not displaying the page except for the specific time range, are you allowed to just not accept orders?

Comment: @JNYRanger : yes, m allowed to do it...i just want to notify user when he/she clicks the final button that sends all orders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DateTime structure has a [TimeOfDay property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A simple algorithm could look like this:

```
DateTime now = ...; // value returned from SELECT GETDATE()
TimeSpan currentTime = now.TimeOfDay;

if (currentTime.Hours >= 8 && currentTime.Hours < 12) {
    ...
}
```

Since TimeSpan implements comparison operators, you can also do the following:

```
DateTime now = ...; // value returned from SELECT GETDATE()
TimeSpan currentTime = now.TimeOfDay;

TimeSpan fromTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
TimeSpan toTime = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);

if (currentTime >= fromTime && currentTime <= toTime) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: please tell me how you compared two different struct...one is datetime (now) and other is timespan (fromtime and to time)

Comment: @user3160395: Oops, sorry, forgot to call TimeOfDay. Should be fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't use DateTime.Now, you can just grab the DateTime object from SQL Server.

I can only guess how you're sending your query to the database, but here's one implementation:

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
using (DbCommand command = database.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT GETDATE()"))
{
    using (IDataReader dataReader = (IDataReader)database.ExecuteReader(command))
    {
        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            currentDateTime = (DateTime)dataReader[0];
        }
    }
}

TimeSpan from = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0); // 8am
TimeSpan to = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0); // 12pm
bool canOrderNow = currentDateTime != DateTime.MinValue && currentDateTime.TimeOfDay >= from && currentDateTime.TimeOfDay < to;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do your date comparisons on the server and make sure that your users know the timezone that they must place their orders. This way when you say between 8am to 12pm, users will know based on their own timezone when to complete their orders.

Comment: thank you, but it will be kind of you to tell me how i can i do the comaparison on server side...any code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql2008 or above .... then you can use time datatype of sql server. You can extract time only using

Sql-server 2008:

’select cast(AttDate as time) [time]
from yourtable’

Earlier versions:

‘select convert(char(5), AttDate, 108) [time]
from yourtable‘

Now compare your data against the above time.

Comment: i am not having tables for dates and times